# What is this tent piece called?

Tags: tents

I have a broken tent piece that I am trying to replace.

[image]
Does anyone know what this piece is called?

This piece forms the canopy of the tent and the poles go into the prongs displayed above. As you can see one of the prongs has become detached and is lost.

This is a piece to a Eureka tent. I could not find the model number on the tent perhaps due to the fact that the tent is 30+ years old and the model number tag has been ripped off.

Comment: I don't know the name but I'd simply take some measurements of the aluminium pipe and would make a new prong.

Comment: That is a tent piece. Made in Thailand. By Eureka for Sears & Ruin a Buck many years ago. & shipped out of Thailand to were ever. The factory is now closed there. Time to make that part yourself.

Comment: Specifying the diameter of the hole in the central part would be a good idea, we may have some specific ideas

Comment: I call that the-piece-that-will-fail-and-that-you-won't-be-able-to-replace, or the-reason-why-I-dislike-dome-tents. But that's maybe a bit long, and probably not that helpful for you.

Comment: more seriously, the prongs look like aluminium tubes, you can probably find a replacement for that one if you know the inner and outer diameter. The red part is probably to ensure a tight fit with the other pieces, possibly a piece of ducktape could be used instead.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! It turns out that the missing prong was inside one of the tent poles! So, after removing it, I was able to reattach the prong to the four-way crown fitting.

Comment: I've heard Boy Scouts call parts similar to that the "tinker toys."  Not sure how widely understood that will be, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## **Tent pole "fitting"**

You can buy tent pole replacement fittings from sites like [this one](http://economytent.com/tent-accessories-2/tent-parts-fittings/), but it's best to buy it from your tent manufacturer. Sometimes your only option is to buy a new complete pole set.

The fitting pictured would be a **four-way *crown* fitting**.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen a part like that in a tent before, but you might try calling it a *boss* or a *hub*. It might be located at the *apex* and take on that name.

Comment: I've seen similar pieces like this.  I think it would be located at the top of the tent and the poles would connect to the 4 pieces protruding out from the center piece (Is that what you meant by apex?)  It's usually seen on external frame tents, like this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN934.jpg.

Comment: @TimmyJim yes, apex as in upper point.  Internal pole frame tents (used to) have a similar piece but without the central disc; perhaps something could be repurposed/adapted.   Caravan awnings (perhaps more of a British thing) use similar poles; that might also be a source of parts (as "junction pieces"). It might also be possible to repair the existing piece.

Answer (score 4):

That is what the leading pole manufacturer DAC would call a 4-way EyePole hub. Here's a three-way version.

[image]

Unfortunately the plastic cap is missing so you can't see the branding. It's quite a specialised item and your only hope is to secure a spare from Eureka. Given the age I'd have thought your chances are slim, but it would be worth a try. If you can't locate the tent model, just send them your picture of the part.

Your only alternative would be to find some strong tubing of a similar diameter and bodge a repair.